# How do I setup an ADODB connection to SQL Server 2008 in Microsoft Access 2010?

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, adodb

I just installed SQL Server 2008 on my laptop. I also have Microsoft Access 2010 installed. Using VBA, I am trying to create an ADODB connection to my own database on SQL Server but I'm having trouble finding the right line of code:

When I use this below, it doesn't work.
The name of my computer is LAPTOPX and the database is HomeSQL.

I am sure it's super easy but since I'm just starting out I can't seem to find the right way to ask the question.

Thanks!

```
Dim DBCONT As Object

Set DBCONT = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim strDbPath As String
strDbPath = "LAPTOPX/HomeSQL"
Dim sConn As String
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source =" & strDbPath & ";" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                        "Persist Security Info=False;"
DBCONT.Open sConn
```

Comment: You are using the wrong connection string, it is for connecting to an access file. You are looking for a connection string to connect to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: just a stupid question: why not using DAO, which is the native method in Access ?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to make sure SQL Native Client is instaled. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/eS-Es/library/ms131321%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

### SQL Server 2008

**Standard security**

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;
```

**Trusted connection**

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

**Connecting to an SQL Server instance**
The syntax of specifying the server instance in the value of the server key is the same for all connection strings for SQL Server.

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;
Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

[Source](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-oledb-provider/)

---

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim sConnString As String
Dim recordsAffected as Long

'Create connection string
sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb; Server=LAPTOPX; Database=HomeSQL; Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Open connection and execute
conn.Open sConnString

'Do your query
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = conn
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = "Select ...;"
  .Execute recordsAffected 'Includes a return parameter to capture the number of records affected
End With

Debug.Print recordsAffected 'Check whether any records were inserted

'Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set cmd = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: @sungod916 make sure HomeSQL is the name of the database, not the SQL Server Instance.

Comment: Might want to add to this answer that `Microsoft ActiveX 2.x` needs to be included as a reference within the project.

Answer (score 1):

This connetion string works under Excel VBA. In MsAccess also should.

```
dbName = "test"          'your database name
dbFilePath = "C:\db.mdf" 'your path to db file

connStr = "Driver={SQL Server native Client 11.0};" & _
          "Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" & _
          "AttachDBFileName=" & dbFilePath & ";" & _
          "Database=" & dbName & ";" & _
          "Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

Full solution: http://straightitsolutions.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-local.html

Comment: Please don't just link to a possible solution, but include the relevant parts.