# vba ActiveX can't create odbc.connection object

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to create ODBC connection in order to be able to perform a simple sql query on one of the tables from my SQL DB.

Below is my code and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I keep getting `ActiveX can't create an object` error and the following line is highlighted: `Set con = CreateObject("ODBC.Connection")`.

```
Private Sub findBtn_Click()

    Dim s
    Dim con As Object 'OdbcConnection
    Dim strCon
    Dim rsSearch
    Dim strSql
    Dim mystring As String
    Dim cmd 'As OdbcCommand

    s = Me.findTxt

    mystring = "Select * from CUSTOMER where CUSTOMER.FORENAME1 like '%" & s &   "%';"

    Set con = CreateObject("ODBC.Connection")

    con.Open "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};" & _
    "Server=localhost;" & _
    "Database=Customers23;" & _
    "UID=admin;" & _
    "PWD=admin;"

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ODBC.Command")
    cmd = mystring
    Me.resTxt = "Connected!"
    MsgBox ("Connected")

End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the standard ADODB library?

Comment: @Mat'sMug The reason for that is that I need to access SQL Server Db and I thought that I had to use External Data => ODBC Datebase to create a link to my SQL Server Db in order to be able to query my SQL DB from Access form. So this assumption isn't correct, is it?

Comment: Yup. You'll want to use ADODB. Good luck!

Comment: @Mat'sMug thank you for your prompt response! One more question, so how do I link my SQL Server Db to my access form then (I mean without External Data => ODBC Database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace ODBC.Connection with ADODB.Connection.

Same with ODBC.Command

You can find an example here [How do I setup an ADODB connection to SQL Server 2008 in Microsoft Access 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345895/how-do-i-setup-an-adodb-connection-to-sql-server-2008-in-microsoft-access-2010)

Also see that link on how to use the Command object.

Comment: Thank you! Will give a go to this approach.

Comment: ODBC allows you to create a name in the system, so you just refer to the connection with an easier to remember name.  ADODB is the control, and he's right that ADODB.Connection is the way to go.